# How to update message without using if statement?

Tags: mpi, hpc

I have a number of processors, let's say, 9, that are arange like a ring together. So, the  processors communicating with each other in a ring and in a non-blocking setting `MPI_Isend() and MPI_Irecv()`. And the task is to recieve the rank of previous proccessor and add that to its own rank, and then pass it to its neighor. This continues until reaching to the processor '0' again. Then processor '0' prints the sum which is n(n+1)/2 ( in this case 45).  I know that these non-blicking function return immediately even if the communication is not finished, and `MPI_Wait()` is needed to ensure the completion of the communication. And I know that it's better to have a buffer of size 2 to store the rank and sum. But I don,t know how and when to update the message before sending it to the next rank?
I don't want to use if statemet. Lik `if(rank==0)` then send to `1` and add then `if(rank==1)` receive from `0` and then add `1` and then send to `2`,... Since this one is highly inefficient for larg number of processor.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
int  size, rank, next, prev;
int  buf[2],
MPI_Request reqs[9];
MPI_Status stats[9];

MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

prev = rank-1;
next = rank+1;
if (rank == 0)  prev = size - 1;
if (rank == (size - 1))  next = 0;

//MPI_Irecv (&buf,count,datatype,source,tag,comm,&request)
ierror = MPI_Irecv(&buf[0], 1, MPI_INT, prev, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[0]);
ierror = MPI_Irecv(&buf[1], 1, MPI_INT, next, tag2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[1]);

//MPI_Isend (&buf,count,datatype,dest,tag,comm,&request)
ierror = MPI_Isend(&buf[0], 1, MPI_INT, prev, tag2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[2]);
ierror = MPI_Isend(&buf[1], 1, MPI_INT, next, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[3]);

ierror = MPI_Waitall(9, reqs, stats);
```

Comment: you need to consider only two cases: `if (rank == 0) {...} else {...}`. use `% rank` to compute `next`. Also, there is no point in using non blocking communication.

Comment: You might want to investigate the use of an *mpi cartesian topology* for establishing a ring of communicating processes.

Comment: @ Gilles Gouaillardet thanks, do you mean somthing like ` prev = (rank + 1) % size;
  next= (rank + size - 1) % size;` . And then in one `if else` doing all send and receives?

Comment: @High Performance Mark  thanks for your suggestion, I'm not that familair with topology, I should start rading that :)

Comment: That's right! Topology can be elegant, but for a 1D ring, this is an overkill imho